# How to post integer value from jquery to python function

Tags: jquery, python, integer

I would like to post an integer value to a python function as follow:

```
var amount = $('#spinner').val();

$.post('http://172.20.194.122:8080/dispense', {pilltype:combo, amount:amount}).done(function (dispensed) {
    $('#testing2').empty().append(dispensed);
});
```

where the value of `$('#spinner') is an integer. 
This is my python function (something like this)

```
def dispense (self, **data):

    pilltype = data['pilltype']
    amount = data['amount']
    count =0
    while (count <=amount)
```

The problem is the value of amount is not an integer so i can't do comparison with `count`. When i print out the type of `amount`

```
print type(amount)
```

I get `<type 'unicode'>`

How do i get integer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it. I just need to transform `amount` into integer by this:

```
amount = int(amount)
```